# css style is applying for something it shouldn't be applied to

Tags: css

I have this css

```
.tableResultClass th, td {padding:18px 28px 18px; text-align:center; }

.tableResultClass th {padding-top:22px; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff; background:#e8eaeb;}

.tableResultClass td {border-top:1px solid #e0e0e0; border-right:1px solid #e0e0e0;}

.tableResultClass tr.odd-row td {background:#f6f6f6;}

.tableResultClass td.first, th.first {text-align:left}

.tableResultClass td.last {border-right:none;}
```

the padding of the `tr` and the `td` is applying for `tableResultClass` and for `pageer` class, although the pageer has no tr and td style.

I know that from firebug, so when I change the values of this style, the width and height ot the `pageer` class is changing , why?

#### html

```
        <td colspan="6"><table>
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><span>1</span></td><td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$GridView1','Page$2')" style="color:White;">2</a></td><td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$GridView1','Page$3')" style="color:White;">3</a></td><td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$GridView1','Page$4')" style="color:White;">4</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table></td>


<table id="BookingTable" runat="server" class="tableResultClass" >
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>ID</th>
                                        <th>PlanTime</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
```

Comment: JSfiddle required...but my guess is that it's the comma in here `.tableResultClass th, td` and `.tableResultClass td.first, th.first {text-align:left}`

Comment: Post the HTML you're applying this to.

Comment: @Paulie_D what should I replace the comma by? do you mean I have to write the whole class?

Comment: Yep, this `.tableResultClass th, td` shoudl be `.tableResultClass th, .tableResultClass td`

Comment: @j08691 I added the html

Comment: @Paulie_D I will try and told you what is the result

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this is due to you not restating the specificity of your classes.

For instance this

```
.tableResultClass th, 
td 
{padding:18px 28px 18px; text-align:center; }
```

should be this

```
.tableResultClass th,
.tableResultClass td 
{padding:18px 28px 18px; text-align:center; }
```

...and so on. Thus

```
.tableResultClass td.first, 
th.first
 {text-align:left}
```

becomes

```
.tableResultClass td.first,
.tableResultClass th.first
 {text-align:left}
```

Comment: And as an addition, if you don't like writing your CSS in this way you could have a look at LESS or SASS (css compressors). When you learn how to code CSS with one of those two (I prefer SASS) your workflow will be extremely faster.